# Почему выдает ошибку в функции

Tags: javascript

Выходит такая ошибка:

> bad[this.id].paused is not a function at HTMLDivElement.

Вот код:

```js
var bad = [];
bad[0] = document.getElementsByClassName('g')[0];
bad[1] = document.getElementsByClassName('s')[0];
bad[2] = document.getElementsByClassName('5')[0];
bad[3] = document.getElementsByClassName('gtl')[0];
bad[4] = document.getElementsByClassName('st')[0];
bad[5] = document.getElementsByClassName('m')[0];
bad[6] = document.getElementsByClassName('antr')[0];
bad[7] = document.getElementsByClassName('lte')[0];
bad[8] = document.getElementsByClassName('cw')[0];
bad[9] = document.getElementsByClassName('l')[0];
bad[10] = document.getElementsByClassName('ff')[0];

var liverpool = document.getElementsByClassName('fuckHorse');
alert(liverpool[0]);
for (var pip = 0; pip < liverpool.length; pip++) {
  liverpool[pip].addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert(bad[this.id]) // нормально выводит элемент
    if (bad[this.id].paused() == true) { //ошибка
      for (var n = 0; n < bad.length; n++) {
        bad[n].pause();
      }
      bad[this.id].play()
    } else {
      bad[this.id].pause()
    }
    alert(this.id);
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="fuckHorse" id='1'><img src="picture_2.jpg" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: bad[10]=document.getElementsByClassName(ff')[0];
кавычка пропущена

Comment: откуда предположение, что вообще есть функция `paused`?